# Django slow performance on processing requests

Tags: django, performance, httpresponse, slowdown

I have a django platform and I've found a strange slow performance when the server tries to response some http requests.

I've managed to isolate a little useless code that shows a strange delay, from which all the others can be derived.

case 1) If I have this function:

```
def get_n_events(request):
    a = request.user
    return HttpResponse("5")
```

the response is very fast, as expected:
[image]

Only 12.61ms, very fast, as expected.

case 2) But if I have this function:

```
def get_n_events(request):
    a = request.user.username
    return HttpResponse("5")
```

the response:
[image]

it takes more than 2 seconds!

How can be this delay explained and how can I avoid this huge time when I need to access the data inside the request? (For example, in my case I need to know the request.user.group_name, but it takes too much tome to get a response.

**UPDATE**

I made some tests with Django Debug Toolbar and I saw that the huge time 
is not due to SQL runtime.
[image]

As we can see, the SQL takes only 183ms, but the request has 1354msecs.
Where does this time come from and how can I reduce it?

Comment: `request.user` is a *lazy* objects, so as long as you do not ask for an attribute, or call `str(..)`, etc. over it, *no* database query is made.

Comment: And is it normal to take more than 2 seconds to access the database and retrieve the name? Is there any way to reduce that time?

Comment: no, but if this is the *first* query, then it can indeed take some time, for example because the connection pool is initialized, etc. If you run this a second time, then often the performance is better.

Comment: Yes, I notice that the first requests is a bit slower, but more than 2 seconds is too much time for a single database SELECT. We need to reduce that time somehow :S

Comment: is this PostgreSQL? PostgreSQL takes some time to *create* a connection, but once that is constructed, then the next ones are all done over the existing ones, so then the time to make the next ones is a lot faster.

Comment: Yes, is postgresSQL. That's why is strange for me to find that 2nd or 3rd requests is also too slow.

Comment: what if you set the [`CONN_MAX_AGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#conn-max-age) to for example `600`?

Comment: I have just tried and I see no difference :(

Comment: well likely there is still something not configuered correctly. Perhaps you better start from an existing PostgreSQL database config in Django, (and thus alter hostname, etc.), also check for firewall issues, etc.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll look for some existing config for postgress in django

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213804/discussion-between-sergio-ferrer-sanchez-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: It seems that all configurations are correct :/

Comment: well two seconds is really strange (unless the database for example runs on a slow machine, at the other side of the world for example), but that is probably not the case.

Comment: Exactly, it's just a postgress DB running in local in my computer, which is a good PC, with ubuntu 18.03. I tried with CONN_MAX_AGE=600 and SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache' but nothing seems to work :/

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end @SergioFerrerSánchez? I have a very similar problem where some of my requests take between 1 and 20 seconds, but the actual work on the DB makes up only 3 to 40ms :(

Answer (score 3):

`request.user` is a *lazy* object, so as long as you do not ask for an attribute, or call `str(..)`, etc. over it, *no* database query is made.

Indeed, if we take a look at the [**`AuthenticationMiddleware`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L15-L23), we see:

> ```
> class AuthenticationMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
>     def process_request(self, request):
>         assert hasattr(request, 'session'), (
>             "The Django authentication middleware requires session middleware "
>             "to be installed. Edit your MIDDLEWARE setting to insert "
>             "'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' before "
>             "'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'."
>         )
>         request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
> ```

So `request.user` presents itself as if it was loaded, but as long as you do not need an attribute, etc. from it, it is just a *proxy* object that *promises* to make a query if necessary.